# Interchanging the order of limit and expectation

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

Assume $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to0}X_t=\gamma\hspace{3pt}a.s.$ where $X_t\geq 0$. 
I would like to show that $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to0}E[X_t]=E[\lim_{t\to0}X_t]=\gamma$, i.e. that it's possible to interchange the order of limit and expectation.

It would be sufficient to show $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to0}E[|X_t-\gamma|]=0$. I can't find a way to use the dominated/monotone convergence theorems, so I am wondering whether the following argument is valid:

$\displaystyle\lim_{t\to0}E[|X_t-\gamma|]
=\lim_{t\to0}E[|X_t-\gamma|{\bf 1}\{|X_t-\gamma|<M\}]
+\lim_{t\to0}E[|X_t-\gamma|{\bf 1}\{|X_t-\gamma|>M\}]$

For the first term we have by using the dominated convergence theorem and the fact that $X_t\to\gamma$ with probability one:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \displaystyle\lim_{t\to0}E[|X_t-\gamma|{\bf 1}\{|X_t-\gamma|<M\}]\\
& =E[\lim_{t\to0}|X_t-\gamma|{\bf 1}\{|X_t-\gamma|<M\}]\\
& =0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

For the second term we have by the inverse of Fatou's lemma and the fact that $X_t\to\gamma$ with probability one: 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \lim_{t\to0}E[|X_t-\gamma|{\bf 1}\{|X_t-\gamma|>M\}]\\
& \leq\limsup_{t\to0}E[|X_t-\gamma|{\bf 1}\{|X_t-\gamma|>M\}]\\
& \leq E[\limsup_{t\to0}|X_t-\gamma|{\bf 1}\{|X_t-\gamma|>M\}]\\
& \leq E[\lim_{t\to0}|X_t-\gamma|{\bf 1}\{|X_t-\gamma|>M\}]\\
& =E[0]\\
& =0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Combining we have $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to0}E[|X_t-\gamma|]=0$

Is this a valid solution or am I cheating somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limsup version of Fatou's lemma only holds if there exists an integrable function $g$, such that $f_n < g$ for all n.  In that case, your proof is valid; if not, there are counter-examples (e.g. $f_n = \gamma + n * 1_{[0,1/n]}$ )